# How do I get VLOOKUP to return a number value of 0 when referencing a blank cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm creating a standard document to pull information from data dumps of varying sizes, up to 1000 rows, into a table.

After pulling from this data, I want to sort the table by one of the columns that contains values in GBP. However, as my table is pulling data from 1000 rows and for arguments sake the data dump is 250 rows, it is pulling over 750 blank cell references. When I sort the column from largest to smallest, it places the 750 blank cell references above the 250 values and then proceeds to sort the 250 values by largest to smallest.

The formula I am using to reference the data is:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'EA Report Here'!E:AY,47,FALSE),"")="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'EA Report Here'!E:AY,47,FALSE),""))
```

The primary function of this formula works as it will not return errors or '0' for blank cells.

What I would like it to do is return the blank cells back as hidden zero values so that they remain at the bottom when sorting the column.

Answer (score 3):

Is `IFNA` what you're after?

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A5,'EA Report Here'!E:AY,47,FALSE),"")
```

---

**Edit** Thanks Jeeped. I believe this one will work on versions older than Excel 2013.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'EA Report Here'!E:AY,47,FALSE),"")
```

Bear in mind both of these result in blank cells as based on question formula, not the numeric value `0`. If you actually want a zero, replace `""` with `0`.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note that [IFNA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626C961-A569-42FC-A49D-79B4951FD461?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) was introduced with xl2013.

Comment: This has worked the same as my current formula. Whilst it is more efficient, when sorting it still places the blank cells above the values. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: In response to the edit - I have avoided using '0' as the cell is then filled with '0'. I'm aiming for the cell to have a value of 0 but show as empty.

Comment: @gms0ulman This has returned the largest number in that column + 1, I have used the same piece of code using 'Min' instead however this still leaves a value in the cell that I would otherwise like to stay blank.

Comment: Apologies, deleted that as now understand you want a min not max. Is `-1` an OK value to use? Basically a blank cell is not equal to numeric value 0, and the question now is what is low enough for Excel to sort it below numeric value 0....

Comment: Its possible I'm asking for the impossible for standard excel formulas. Using Min with 0 or -1 still returns a value in the field. If I were to create a table of data with no formulas and there were blank cells in that column, sorting it would place the empty cells at the bottom. When I use a VLOOKUP I cant get the same result as excel seems to place the referenced blank cell value higher than the cells with actual numbers in them.